# LivewView of .NET maui shows emtpy rows when running published app on mac

Tags: .net, macos, maui

In the efforts of learning .NET MAUI, I tried use ListView like following:

```
            <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="searchResults"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:AwsHomeViewModel}}, Path=SearchResult}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAwsProfile}"
                BackgroundColor="Black">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="White"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

When debugging my app on mac using mac version of Visual Studio 2022, I am able to see the ListView was populated with AWS profiles. However, after publishing it and running the published app, I see empty rows.

This behavior is sporadic depending on updating .net framework or updating Visual Studio, or etc.

Is it a known issue?

[Running ListView in debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8k5F.png)

[Running ListView in published app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Wk1.png)

Note that when I select the same row in both app, I am able to selected AWS profile.

My work env: Macbook Pro 2023, Apple M2 Pro, 32GB Memory, macOS 13.5.2 (22G91), Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.6
Target Framework: .NET 7.0

I expected to see my AWS profiles in the published app.

Comment: _This behavior is sporadic depending on updating .net framework or updating Visual Studio_ Did you mean it works well before you upfate the Visual Studio? Did you try in release mode? Did you use any third party nuget?

Comment: You may try [Using compiled bindings in a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate).

Comment: I haven't kept tracking of versions. But it's was working with my initial trial. After updating Visual Studio on mac, it's happening. One interesting note is that same ListView in other pages working well.

Comment: You could try setting a x:DataType attribute for DataTemplate.